# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL help. jquery

Tags: jquery

For some reason my code stopped working for my calculator and I don't know why I keep getting the error above every time I try to multiply with it. But it used to work. I don't know why it quit working. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Button:eq(0)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val().slice(0, -1));
    });
    $(".Button:eq(1)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val(null);
    });
    $(".Button:eq(2)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "-");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(3)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "/");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(4)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "1");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(5)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "2");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(6)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "3");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(7)").click(function(){
            $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "X");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(8)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "4");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(9)").click(function(){
    $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "5");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(10)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "6");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(11)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "-");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(12)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "7");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(13)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "8");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(14)").click(function(){
            $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "9");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(15)").click(function(){
            $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "0");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(16)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + ".");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(17)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "+");
    });
    $(".Button:eq(18)").click(function(){
        $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val().replace("x", "*"));
        $("#Num_View").val(eval($("#Num_View").val()));
    });
});
```

Comment: when is the error coming

Comment: You should post the exact error message as shown by Chrome console or whatever browser you are using

Comment: Syntax errors are best found using automated tools (ideally, the IDE), not by posting the code to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Somehow I think using `eval` on user input is a _bad_ idea.

Comment: also, somehow I don't think you should identify the buttons by their DOM order. What if you find out that you have misplaced some button, or you decide to implement different skins (with different button layout) later on?

Answer (score 1):

Either use small `x` or Capital `X` but same at both places.

```
$("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "X");
                                         //^ capital X here
```

you code don't work as

```
$("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val().replace("x", "*"));
                                              // ^  you are small x here
```

Comment: This doesn't exlain the syntax error, does it?

Comment: @JanDvorak it might sir as he is using eval function on it .

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps that's what makes `eval` so evil? :-) (point taken; didn't notice the `eval`)

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah Small little powerful Devil `eval` .

Comment: @TusharGupta Thank you I did not notice that little problem as soon as I changed that it started working.

Comment: @CDW Welocme Happy to help :)